# react-native-twitter Oath URLSearchParams Error on IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, oauth, twitter-oauth

Currently implementing Twitter's API on an IOS App **RN 0.61.1** and using the [react-native-twitter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-twitter), library but am running into problems following the example on [github](https://github.com/Piroro-hs/react-native-twitter).

Clicking the auth button returns an error. The expected result should be a browser page pop up, which allows user to grant access to twitter through the app.

I have found similar issues with react-native and [OAuth](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/3183) but none of the suggestions work in my case.

**In Debugger:ERROR**

> setUpDeveloperTools.js:73 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
>   Error: not implemented
>   Error: not implemented
>       at URLSearchParams.get (http://localhost:8081/index.delta?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&revisionId=306550084ac919f0:40695:15...

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is allowed but I edited the module itself since it didn't work in `index.js`.

Located the `auth()` function through the debugger and changed the `URLSearchParams` import.

```
//in ./node_modules/react-native-twitter/src/oauth/auth.js 

//from
import URLSearchParams from 'url-search-params';


//to
import {URLSearchParams } from 'whatwg-url';
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';
global.Buffer = Buffer;
```

Suggested [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23922#issuecomment-476070032).